# Help with dual boot - Windows 10 & Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows, kubuntu

I'm trying to install KUbuntu 15.10 on dual boot with Windows 10. I installed KUbuntu without any problem but on a boot BIOS isnt recognizing KUbuntu.

I have UEFI but I dont have a option to use Legacy Mode, I can only disable UEFI. I tried to enable and disable UEFI but BIOS isnt detecting KUbuntu anyway. I tried to use several Linux distributions like Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mate & openSUSE but I'm having a same issue.

Can someone help me please? I followed almost all online tutorials but I wasnt able to fix it. I'm not sure if there's any difference if I use 32bit Linux considering that my Windows 10 is 64bit.

I had Ubuntu, Debian and Linux Mint on a same notebook while I was on Windows 8.1 (64bit) and I never had any issue but I'm not sure if I used 64bit versions of Linux distributions or 32bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't installed Kubuntu, but when booting from CD or USB it gives you the option to boot from UEFI CD/USB or boot from CD/USB.

If you have UEFI active then you should install using that option.  If you have Windows installed using UEFI you need to use the UEFI option.

64bit and 32bit should have no effect.

When you boot from a live CD can you see your Kubuntu partitions?

If you can it installed correctly.  If you cannot then you need to install using my recommendations.